# Unable to type alias a specialised generic enum

Tags: enums, rust

Given the following:

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum A<T: Debug> {
    X,
    Y(T),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct B;

type C = A<B>;
// use A<B> as C; // Does not compile
```

I can use it as:

```
fn main() {
    let val0 = A::X::<B>;
    let val1 = A::Y::<B>(B);
    println!("{:?}\t{:?}", val0, val1);
}
```

But then for more than one generic parameter (or if `A`, `B` etc were much longer names then to alias it I tried the following but it doesn't compile:

```
fn main() {
    let val0 = C::X;
    let val1 = C::Y(B);
    println!("{:?}\t{:?}", val0, val1);
}
```

with errors:

```
src/main.rs:656:16: 656:20 error: no associated item named `X` found for type `A<B>` in the current scope
src/main.rs:656     let val0 = C::X;
                               ^~~~
src/main.rs:657:16: 657:20 error: no associated item named `Y` found for type `A<B>` in the current scope
src/main.rs:657     let val1 = C::Y(B);
```

As also noted i am unable to use `use` to solve the problem. Is there a way around it (because typing the whole thing seems to be cumbersome) ?

```
rustc --version
rustc 1.9.0 (e4e8b6668 2016-05-18)
```

Comment: Sounds like missing functionality...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way around it (because typing the whole thing seems to be cumbersome)?

You can specify `C` as the type of the variable so you can use `A::X` or `A::Y` without explicit specifying the type parameter:

```
let val0: C = A::X;
let val1: C = A::Y(B);
```

Comment: whoa ! Never could have guessed that - i gave up when `C::X` failed. But the fact it works this way (while not the other way) seems a bit of an  obfuscation, no ? Nonetheless it solves my issue of typing template parameters everywhere so thanks !

Comment: @ustulation I *believe* the thing is that `A` the *type* and `A` the *namespace* are different things as far as the compiler knows.  `type` takes care of the former, not the latter.  Not a great state of affairs, but them's the breaks.  I'd expect it to get improved at *some* point.